# How and where to declare a mutex

Tags: c, threadpool, mutex

I'm new to threading and I'm trying to figure out, why in this implementation of a threadpool with queue there is a mutex (dstrymutex)
that is defined in the c file and not as part of the struct threadpool as all the other mutexes. Is there a reason for this?
And while we are at it, I would love to know the correct place to declare mutexes that are being used in the same way they are used here.
Thanks a lot!

Here is the code:
h file:

```
#ifndef __THREAD_POOL__
#define __THREAD_POOL__

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "osqueue.h"


#define FAILURE -1
#define SUCCESS 0
#define DONT_WAIT_FOR_TASKS 0

typedef struct thread_pool
{
     //The field x is here because a struct without fields
     //doesn't compile. Remove it once you add fields of your own
     int numOfThreads;
     pthread_t* threads;
     struct os_queue* tasksQueue;
     pthread_mutex_t lock;
     pthread_mutex_t queueLock;
     pthread_cond_t notify;
     int stopped;
     int canInsert;
}ThreadPool;

/**
 * creates a thread pool struct.
 * @param numOfThreads number of threads in the thread pool.
 * @return reference to new thread pool struct if succeeded, NULL if failed.
 */
ThreadPool* tpCreate(int numOfThreads);

/**
 * Destroys the thread pool.
 * @param threadPool thread pool
 * @param shouldWaitForTasks 0 - dont wait for tasks in the queue, else - wait for tasks.
 */
void tpDestroy(ThreadPool* threadPool, int shouldWaitForTasks);

/**
 * inserts a task to the tasks queue of the thread pool.
 * @param threadPool thread pool
 * @param computeFunc task
 * @param param argument to the task
 * @return 0- success , -1 - fail
 */
int tpInsertTask(ThreadPool* threadPool, void (*computeFunc) (void *), void* param);

#endif
```

c file:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "threadPool.h"
#define STDERR_FD 2
#define SYS_CALL_FAILURE 10

pthread_mutex_t destryLock;

typedef struct task
{
    void (*computeFunc)(void *param);
    void* param;
}Task;

/**
 * prints error in sys call to stderr.
 */
void printErrorInSysCallToSTDERR() {
    char error_msg[] = "Error in system call\n";
    write(STDERR_FD, error_msg, sizeof(error_msg));
}

/**
 * threads function. tasks are taken and executed by the threads in the thread pool from the tasks queue.
 * @param args expected ThreadPool*
 * @return void
 */
void* execute(void* args) {
    ThreadPool* tp = (ThreadPool*)args;
    struct os_queue* taskQueue = tp->tasksQueue;
    printf("New thread was created\n");

    while (!tp->stopped && !(tp->canInsert == 0 && osIsQueueEmpty(taskQueue))) {
        /* Lock must be taken to wait on conditional variable */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(tp->queueLock));

        /* Wait on condition variable, check for spurious wakeups.
           When returning from pthread_cond_wait(), we own the lock. */
        if((osIsQueueEmpty(taskQueue)) && (!tp->stopped)) {
            printf("Busy\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&(tp->notify), &(tp->queueLock));
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tp->queueLock));

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(tp->lock));
        if (!(osIsQueueEmpty(taskQueue))) {
            // take task from the queue
            Task* task = osDequeue(taskQueue);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tp->lock));
            // execute task
            task->computeFunc(task->param);
            free(task);
        }
        else {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tp->lock));
        }
    }
}

/**
 * creates a thread pool struct.
 * @param numOfThreads number of threads in the thread pool.
 * @return reference to new thread pool struct if succeeded, NULL if failed.
 */
ThreadPool* tpCreate(int numOfThreads) {
    int out = open("output",  O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, 0644);
    if (out == -1) {
        printf("Failed to open output file\n");
        printErrorInSysCallToSTDERR();
        exit(SYS_CALL_FAILURE);
    }
    // replace standard output with output file
    if (dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to operate dup2 for out\n");
        printErrorInSysCallToSTDERR();
        exit(SYS_CALL_FAILURE);
    }

    ThreadPool* tp = (ThreadPool*)malloc(sizeof(ThreadPool));
    if (tp == NULL) {
        printf("Failure: allocate memory for thread pool struct");
        return NULL;
    }
    tp->numOfThreads = numOfThreads;

    tp->threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * tp->numOfThreads);
    if (tp->threads == NULL) {
        printf("Failure: allocate memory for threads array");
        return NULL;
    }

    tp->tasksQueue = osCreateQueue();
    pthread_mutex_init(&(tp->lock), NULL);
    tp->stopped = 0;
    tp->canInsert = 1;

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&(tp->queueLock), NULL) != 0 ||
            pthread_mutex_init(&(tp->queueLock), NULL) != 0 ||
            pthread_cond_init(&(tp->notify), NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Failure: initialize one required mutex or more\n");
        tpDestroy(tp, 0);
        return NULL;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < tp->numOfThreads; i++) {
         if(pthread_create(&(tp->threads[i]), NULL, execute, (void *)tp) != 0) {
             printf("Failure: creating a thread failed.\n");
         }
    }

    return tp;
}

/**
 * inserts a task to the tasks queue of the thread pool.
 * @param threadPool thread pool
 * @param computeFunc task
 * @param param argument to the task
 * @return 0- success , -1 - fail
 */
int tpInsertTask(ThreadPool* threadPool, void (*computeFunc) (void *), void* param) {
    if(threadPool == NULL || computeFunc == NULL) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    if (!(threadPool->canInsert)) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    Task* task = (Task*)malloc(sizeof(Task));
    if (task == NULL) {
        printf("Failure: allocate memory for threads array");
        return FAILURE;
    }

    task->computeFunc = computeFunc;
    task->param = param;

    osEnqueue(threadPool->tasksQueue, (void *)task);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadPool->queueLock));
    // wake up thread that wait as long as the tasks queue is empty
    if(pthread_cond_signal(&(threadPool->notify)) != 0) {
        printf("Failure: signal opertion in tpInsertTask\n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(threadPool->queueLock));
    return SUCCESS;
}

/**
 * Destroys the thread pool.
 * @param threadPool thread pool
 * @param shouldWaitForTasks 0 - dont wait for tasks in the queue, else - wait for tasks.
 */
void tpDestroy(ThreadPool* threadPool, int shouldWaitForTasks) {
    if (threadPool == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&destryLock);
    // first time enter to tpDestory with valid thread pool
    if ( threadPool->canInsert != 0) {
        threadPool->canInsert = 0;
        // make sure tpDestroy will ne called only once for thr thread pool
    } else {
        return;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&destryLock);


    if (shouldWaitForTasks == DONT_WAIT_FOR_TASKS) {
        threadPool->stopped = 1;
    }
    int i, err;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(threadPool->queueLock));

    /* Wake up all worker threads */
    if((pthread_cond_broadcast(&(threadPool->notify)) != 0) ||
       (pthread_mutex_unlock(&(threadPool->queueLock)) != 0)) {
        printf("Exit due failure in tpDestory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < threadPool->numOfThreads; i++) {
        err = pthread_join(threadPool->threads[i], NULL);
        if (err != 0) {
            printf("Failure: waiting for thread no. %d\n", i);
        }
    }


    threadPool->stopped = 1;

    //free memory
    while (!osIsQueueEmpty(threadPool->tasksQueue)) {
        printf("Task was erased from tasks queue\n");
        Task* task = osDequeue(threadPool->tasksQueue);
        free(task);
    }

    osDestroyQueue(threadPool->tasksQueue);
    free(threadPool->threads);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(threadPool->lock));
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(threadPool->queueLock));
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&destryLock);
    free(threadPool);
}
```

Comment: You mean destryLock?

Comment: Um. Whoever that author is, they need a refresher course on abandoning mutexes. They lock `destroyLock`, then just flat out `return;` if `threadPool->canInsert ` is zero. Woe be unto whoever is next in line to try that; they'll be waiting awhile. That code has "someone other than the author added `destroyLock` after the fact" written all over it.

Comment: yes I meant destryLock.

Comment: WhozCraig, can you elaborate on what you meant and how to fix it?
I'm not sure I understood...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also its ridiculous to drop one letter from a word to “abbreviate” it. Just makes it harder to spell. Anal retentive, I know, but annoying crap like that adds up. ‘dstryLck’ or ‘destroyLock’, the latter hardly being crazy long...

Comment: @zzxyz Surely 'dstryLck' is short for 'Does Try Luck'.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me how to fix that mistake that WhozCraig pointed out?
Thanks!

Comment: In `tpDestroy`, when you do the `return`, you are leaving the function with the `destryLock` mutex _locked_--not what you want. Add a `pthread_mutex_unlock(&destryLock);` _before_ the `return` (in the `else` clause). Do _not_ move the old one (just below the `else` clause)--add a new one.

Comment: thank you very much all. If its not too much to ask I would love to get an answer to my original question about the reason, if there is one, to define the destryLock not as part of the threadpool struct. Or more generally how should the mutexes be defined correctly?

Comment: @elihar The short answer is that in this particular case, the way the lock is used, it is effectively global (2 different thread pools objects would have to go through the lock section one at a time, even though that's not necessary to ensure what the locking area is trying to ensure (that each threadpool only gets destroyed once)).  So, in this case, it's wrong.  There's probably other wrong things, which is why the slow answer.

Comment: So can you please tell me the correct way I should use it?

Comment: @elihar - Well, a good start is moving it into the threadpool struct and initializing it in the same place the others are being initialized in.  The problem there being I think there are other logic problems, such as dequeueing an object associated with that threadpool using the `lock` mutex potentially while the threadpool is being destroyed.

Comment: @elihar - If I was responsible for this code, I would probably spend half a day studying it, double-checking documentation, etc.  Certainly at least one person who had no clue what they were doing has worked on it.  Anyway, point being without spending more time than I have available, i'd be reluctant to offer concrete advice.  That said, moving the mutex into the struct couldn't hurt anything, but is unlikely to help anything either, since there is almost certainly only one threadpool object.

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely clear from the code what the intent of the `destryLock` mutex is, especially since it's not initialized with the [`PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) static initializer, nor is it initialized with `pthread_mutex_init`. It is destroyed however in that `tpDestroy` function, so any calls to [`pthread_mutex_lock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) are likely producing the `EINVAL` error.

That being said, based on what `tpDestroy` looks like it's *supposed* to do, that is, destroy the thread pool object created with `tpCreate`, it's not clear in that code what the intent was for the logic; it should be noted that a deadlock condition can occur with this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&destryLock);
// first time enter to tpDestory with valid thread pool
if ( threadPool->canInsert != 0) {
    threadPool->canInsert = 0;
    // make sure tpDestroy will ne called only once for thr thread pool
} else {
    return; // dead lock since not unlocking after having locked
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&destryLock);
```

This leads one to believe that this code was built (at least in part) by someone who didn't fully understand multi-threading, or didn't quite understand how the design was to fit with the thread pool.

It would make sense to put the `destryLock` mutex within the thread pool struct itself since the function is operating on the thread pool object passed in, and not on a global one.

> I would love to know the correct place to declare mutexes that are being used in the same way they are used here.

This question is a little broad given your understanding of multi-threading and synchronization primitives, instead, I'll focus on *why* you want a mutex versus *where* you want it.

A mutex allows for areas of code to be blocked off by multiple threads so that only one thread can access the code at a time. You do this because it's entirely possible on multi-core systems for multiple threads to access the same data at the same time, thus causing race conditions to occur and thus undefined behavior to occur.

If you want to block off code from multiple threads, then the *where* can become a little more clear since you'll be able to ascertain if a mutex should be a global/local static object, or if it should be a member object.

As an example, say I have a game with a bunch of enemies; I'll likely keep the set of enemies in a list of some sort. When I want to iterate over the list of enemies, say for collision detection, AI or other game effects, if I have multiple threads in my game acting on the enemy list, I might want a mutex to lock on the entire list while I preform whatever game logic on the enemies so the state of the enemies can be accurate for all threads. This however might not be the best option since it can introduce lag; instead, I might want a mutex on each enemy and only lock on the enemy who's affected by the logic.

So it's more about what objects with a mutable state you want to protect.

I hope that can help.